# Can not get one item out of Json

Tags: json, angularjs

tryign to pull the items from this json, it dosent work, any suggestions?

```
   <pre>{{statistics|json}}</pre>

<div class = "list">
        <a class =" item" 
           ng-repeat="item in statistics ">




         <p class="title"> {{item.token}} </p>  


        </a>
</div>
```

this is the json code: im working on a server so u cant run it..

```
app.controller('StatisticsCtrl',
        ['$scope',
          '$auth',
          'StatisticsService',
           function ($scope, $auth, StatisticsService) {

               var token = $auth.getToken(); //meant to cancel token undefined error

               console.log('StatisticsCtrl INIT');

                function run() {
                    var data = {
                        token: token,
                        timestamp_from: moment(new Date()).unix()-30 * 24 * 3600,
                        timestamp_till: moment(new Date()).unix(),
                        order: 'duration_minutes',
                        limit: 20

                    };
                    StatisticsService.getStatisticsFromServer(data).then(function (response) {

                        console.log('syncStatistics', JSON.stringify(response));

                        $scope.statistics = response;  // bring response to statistics,the jason comes from here



                    }, function (error) {
                        console.error(error);
                    });
                }

                run();

            }]);
```

i get only the  i have a feeling its something about the seting of the json itself..

Comment: not helpful, html is alrite, share the angular code as to how the json is returned. Did you parse the json?

Comment: What does console.log($scope.statistics); print?

Comment: its ok, i fixed it..

Comment: Then delete your question.

Comment: or write up an answer